# Connect the dot vertically instead of horizontally on Line Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart which shows multiple lines. X-axis represents date and Y-axis represents numeric reading. The lines represent the category **PZ-1, PZ-2 & PZ-3**. I have managed to remove the horizontal line that connect between the dots but now I want to connect the dots vertically that aligns based on the date on X-axis. I do not want to rotate the line or swap X-axis position with Y-axis and vice versa. Does anyone know how I can achieve the vertical line? Thank you

Below is my current code:

```js
    const data = {
      datasets: [
        {label: 'PZ-1',data:[{x:'2022-02-25', y:40.551},{x:'2022-03-01', y:35.889},{x:'2022-03-02', y:34.68},{x:'2022-03-03', y:33.182},{x:'2022-03-04', y:30.82},{x:'2022-03-05', y:29.864},{x:'2022-03-08', y:28.413},{x:'2022-03-10', y:28.413},{x:'2022-03-12', y:28.424},{x:'2022-03-15', y:25.578},{x:'2022-03-17', y:27.07},{x:'2022-03-19', y:27.42},{x:'2022-03-22', y:27.478},{x:'2022-03-24', y:22.817},{x:'2022-03-26', y:22.576},{x:'2022-03-29', y:22.326},{x:'2022-03-31', y:22.011},{x:'2022-04-02', y:21.672},{x:'2022-04-05', y:21.561},{x:'2022-04-07', y:21.307},{x:'2022-04-09', y:34.988},{x:'2022-04-12', y:28.89},{x:'2022-04-14', y:28.618},{x:'2022-04-17', y:28.862},{x:'2022-04-19', y:27.727},{x:'2022-04-21', y:27.493},{x:'2022-04-23', y:27.149},{x:'2022-04-26', y:25.862},{x:'2022-04-28', y:25.59},{x:'2022-04-30', y:25.37},{x:'2022-05-04', y:24.79},{x:'2022-05-06', y:24.927}],backgroundColor: '#778899',borderColor: '#778899',borderWidth: 1,showLine: false},{label: 'PZ-2',data:[{x:'2022-02-22', y:40.994},{x:'2022-03-01', y:55.537},{x:'2022-03-02', y:62.907},{x:'2022-03-03', y:59.462},{x:'2022-03-04', y:55.175},{x:'2022-03-05', y:53.294},{x:'2022-03-08', y:50.284},{x:'2022-03-10', y:49.89},{x:'2022-03-12', y:50.334},{x:'2022-03-15', y:47.137},{x:'2022-03-17', y:48.726},{x:'2022-03-19', y:48.294},{x:'2022-03-22', y:48.002},{x:'2022-03-24', y:40.156},{x:'2022-03-26', y:39.857},{x:'2022-03-29', y:39.678},{x:'2022-03-31', y:39.331},{x:'2022-04-02', y:36.719},{x:'2022-04-05', y:36.438},{x:'2022-04-07', y:36.258},{x:'2022-04-09', y:72.891},{x:'2022-04-12', y:59.97},{x:'2022-04-14', y:59.578},{x:'2022-04-17', y:59.781},{x:'2022-04-19', y:60.408},{x:'2022-04-21', y:60.309},{x:'2022-04-23', y:59.82},{x:'2022-04-26', y:61.679},{x:'2022-04-28', y:61.539},{x:'2022-04-30', y:61.187},{x:'2022-05-04', y:59.871},{x:'2022-05-06', y:59.63}],backgroundColor: '#DB7093',borderColor: '#DB7093',borderWidth: 1,showLine: false},{label: 'PZ-3',data:[{x:'2022-02-22', y:51.455},{x:'2022-03-01', y:44.882},{x:'2022-03-02', y:58.791},{x:'2022-03-03', y:55.118},{x:'2022-03-04', y:48.364},{x:'2022-03-05', y:47.498},{x:'2022-03-08', y:45.477},{x:'2022-03-10', y:44.859},{x:'2022-03-12', y:45.468},{x:'2022-03-15', y:39.599},{x:'2022-03-17', y:40.561},{x:'2022-03-19', y:39.993},{x:'2022-03-22', y:40.232},{x:'2022-03-24', y:33.061},{x:'2022-03-26', y:33.169},{x:'2022-03-29', y:32.99},{x:'2022-03-31', y:32.849},{x:'2022-04-02', y:31.811},{x:'2022-04-05', y:31.412},{x:'2022-04-07', y:31.223},{x:'2022-04-09', y:84.506},{x:'2022-04-12', y:74.415},{x:'2022-04-14', y:74.079},{x:'2022-04-17', y:73.876},{x:'2022-04-19', y:87.873},{x:'2022-04-21', y:87.748},{x:'2022-04-23', y:87.45},{x:'2022-04-26', y:76.555},{x:'2022-04-28', y:76.401},{x:'2022-04-30', y:76.649},{x:'2022-05-04', y:75.585},{x:'2022-05-06', y:75.748}],backgroundColor: '#8B008B',borderColor: '#8B008B',borderWidth: 1,showLine: false}
    ]
    };
    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      options: {
        layout: {
          padding: {
            left: 5
          }
        },
        indexAxis: 'x',
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          },
          x:{
            reverse: false,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                  tooltipFormat: 'dd-MMM-yy',
                  displayFormats: {
                        day: 'dd-MMM-yy'
                    }
                },
            ticks: {
              source: 'date',
              autoSkip: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
```

```css
    * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
          }
          .chartCard {
            overflow:auto;
            background: rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2);
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          .chartBox {
            padding: 20px;        
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
            background: white;
          }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Line Chart</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart" style="position: relative;height:1200px;width:1400px"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) and define a `beforeDraw` hook that draws the lines directly on the `canvas` through the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
const data = {
  datasets: [
        {label: 'PZ-1',data:[{x:'2022-02-25', y:40.551},{x:'2022-03-01', y:35.889},{x:'2022-03-02', y:34.68},{x:'2022-03-03', y:33.182},{x:'2022-03-04', y:30.82},{x:'2022-03-05', y:29.864},{x:'2022-03-08', y:28.413},{x:'2022-03-10', y:28.413},{x:'2022-03-12', y:28.424},{x:'2022-03-15', y:25.578},{x:'2022-03-17', y:27.07},{x:'2022-03-19', y:27.42},{x:'2022-03-22', y:27.478},{x:'2022-03-24', y:22.817},{x:'2022-03-26', y:22.576},{x:'2022-03-29', y:22.326},{x:'2022-03-31', y:22.011},{x:'2022-04-02', y:21.672},{x:'2022-04-05', y:21.561},{x:'2022-04-07', y:21.307},{x:'2022-04-09', y:34.988},{x:'2022-04-12', y:28.89},{x:'2022-04-14', y:28.618},{x:'2022-04-17', y:28.862},{x:'2022-04-19', y:27.727},{x:'2022-04-21', y:27.493},{x:'2022-04-23', y:27.149},{x:'2022-04-26', y:25.862},{x:'2022-04-28', y:25.59},{x:'2022-04-30', y:25.37},{x:'2022-05-04', y:24.79},{x:'2022-05-06', y:24.927}],backgroundColor: '#778899',borderColor: '#778899',borderWidth: 1,showLine: false},{label: 'PZ-2',data:[{x:'2022-02-22', y:40.994},{x:'2022-03-01', y:55.537},{x:'2022-03-02', y:62.907},{x:'2022-03-03', y:59.462},{x:'2022-03-04', y:55.175},{x:'2022-03-05', y:53.294},{x:'2022-03-08', y:50.284},{x:'2022-03-10', y:49.89},{x:'2022-03-12', y:50.334},{x:'2022-03-15', y:47.137},{x:'2022-03-17', y:48.726},{x:'2022-03-19', y:48.294},{x:'2022-03-22', y:48.002},{x:'2022-03-24', y:40.156},{x:'2022-03-26', y:39.857},{x:'2022-03-29', y:39.678},{x:'2022-03-31', y:39.331},{x:'2022-04-02', y:36.719},{x:'2022-04-05', y:36.438},{x:'2022-04-07', y:36.258},{x:'2022-04-09', y:72.891},{x:'2022-04-12', y:59.97},{x:'2022-04-14', y:59.578},{x:'2022-04-17', y:59.781},{x:'2022-04-19', y:60.408},{x:'2022-04-21', y:60.309},{x:'2022-04-23', y:59.82},{x:'2022-04-26', y:61.679},{x:'2022-04-28', y:61.539},{x:'2022-04-30', y:61.187},{x:'2022-05-04', y:59.871},{x:'2022-05-06', y:59.63}],backgroundColor: '#DB7093',borderColor: '#DB7093',borderWidth: 1,showLine: false},{label: 'PZ-3',data:[{x:'2022-02-22', y:51.455},{x:'2022-03-01', y:44.882},{x:'2022-03-02', y:58.791},{x:'2022-03-03', y:55.118},{x:'2022-03-04', y:48.364},{x:'2022-03-05', y:47.498},{x:'2022-03-08', y:45.477},{x:'2022-03-10', y:44.859},{x:'2022-03-12', y:45.468},{x:'2022-03-15', y:39.599},{x:'2022-03-17', y:40.561},{x:'2022-03-19', y:39.993},{x:'2022-03-22', y:40.232},{x:'2022-03-24', y:33.061},{x:'2022-03-26', y:33.169},{x:'2022-03-29', y:32.99},{x:'2022-03-31', y:32.849},{x:'2022-04-02', y:31.811},{x:'2022-04-05', y:31.412},{x:'2022-04-07', y:31.223},{x:'2022-04-09', y:84.506},{x:'2022-04-12', y:74.415},{x:'2022-04-14', y:74.079},{x:'2022-04-17', y:73.876},{x:'2022-04-19', y:87.873},{x:'2022-04-21', y:87.748},{x:'2022-04-23', y:87.45},{x:'2022-04-26', y:76.555},{x:'2022-04-28', y:76.401},{x:'2022-04-30', y:76.649},{x:'2022-05-04', y:75.585},{x:'2022-05-06', y:75.748}],backgroundColor: '#8B008B',borderColor: '#8B008B',borderWidth: 1,showLine: false}]};
   
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    beforeDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaaaaa';
      var xAxis = chart.scales.x;
      var yAxis = chart.scales.y;
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((t, i) => { 
        const dateString = moment(t.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const values = chart.data.datasets
                         .filter((ds, i) => !chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden)
                         .map(ds => ds.data.find(v => v.x == dateString))
                         .filter(v => v != undefined)
                         .map(o => o.y);  
        if (values.length > 1) {                 
          var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(i);  
          var yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(Math.max(...values));  
          var yBottom = yAxis.getPixelForValue(Math.min(...values));               
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, yBottom);
          ctx.lineTo(x, yTop);
          ctx.stroke();
        }        
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data,
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 5
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true        
      },
      x: {
        offset: true,
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          tooltipFormat: 'dd-MMM-yy',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'dd-MMM-yy'
          }
        },
        grid: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          source: 'date',
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart('myChart', config );
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="140"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! you have been a great help